# MySql using inner join along with union distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

How to I add a inner join to the following union distinct query?

```
select cn_to from connections a where cn_from = '111'
union distinct
select cn_from from connections b where cn_to = '111'
inner join names on connections.cn_to = names.id
```

The tables are `names` and `connections`. The first query works fine. Things fail at the `inner join` part. Can you please help?

Table creates and inserts are here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca27bf/1

I'm trying to get results like this

```
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 6
Name 7
Name Odd
```

Comment: Can you execute the second SELECT stand-alone?

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
select c.cn_to
from connections c
where c.cn_from = '111'
union distinct
select c.cn_from
from connections c join
     names n
     on c.cn_to = n.id
where c.cn_to = '111';
```

`WHERE` and `FROM` are clauses in the `SELECT` statement.  `JOIN` is an operation *only understood in the `FROM` clause*.  So your clauses are misplaced.

This assumes that your database supports `union distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `UNION` query as a derived table and then `JOIN` that to the `names` table:

```
SELECT cn, names.name
FROM (select cn_to AS cn from connections a where cn_from = '111'
union distinct
select cn_from from connections b where cn_to = '111') c
join names on c.cn = names.id
```

Output:

```
cn      name
222     Name 2
333     Name 3
444     Name 4
555     Name 5
666     Name 6
777     Name 7
121     Name Odd
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca27bf/6)

Answer (score 0):

what you want to select cn_to or name??
if you want names for cn_from = '111' or cn_to = '111' : **select names.name from connections inner join  names on connections.cn_to = names.id where cn_from = '111' or cn_to = '111';**

result : 
name
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 1
Name 1
Name 1
Name 1
link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca27bf/13

Comment: Hi, when you are not sure about the question please post your questions through the comment section.